# How to extract "StrB(StrC,StrD)(StrE)" from "StrA(StrB(StrC,StrD)(StrE)) StrF " in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I tried to use this:`Regex.Match(input, @"\(([^)]*)\)")`, but this will give me "(StrB(StrC,StrD)" which is not what I want.

I want to extract the string between 2 parentheses, but the string that is inside can have its own set of parentheses that is nested inside the main 2 parentheses and the string can be infinitely nested with parentheses like:

`"a(b(c(d(...))))"` , Any idea how this is done?
Thanks.

Comment: Mustafa, where are the brackets..? do you mean the Parenthesis ?

Comment: You can use/write a simple stateful lexer for this.

Comment: do you want your output to look like this `"A","B","C,D","E","F"`

Comment: you can try something like this .. if it works I will post it as an Answer..
`var strToSplit = "StrA(StrB(StrC,StrD)(StrE)) StrF";`
`var strArray = strToSplit.Replace("Str","").Split(new string[] {"(",")"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Good luck. (+1 for correct terminology on other comment)

Comment: @DJKRAZE: I think `Str` is just a placeholder for the real thing...

Comment: -1 Mustafa, It would be nice to see an actual example ...that's why I down vote questions of this nature.. poor quality

Comment: @DJKRAZE I'm coding an interpreter, so this is a good example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get what you want:

```
var regex = new Regex(
    @"(?<=\()(?:[^()]|(?<br>\()|(?<-br>\)))*(?(br)(?!))(?=\))");
var input = "StrA(StrB(StrC,StrD)(StrE)) StrF";
var matches = regex.Matches(input);
```

The regular expression breaks down as follows:

```
(?<=\()         Preceeded by a (
(?:             Don't bother capturing a group
     [^()]+     Match one or more non-brackets
     |          OR
     (?<br>\()  Capture a (, increment the br count
     |          OR
     (?<-br>\)) Capture a ), decrement the br count or fail if it's 0
                (failing here will mean we've reached the end of our match)   
)
*               Zero or more times
(?(br)(?!))     Fail if there's the br count is greater than zero
                 (Literally, if it's greater than zero, match a (?!);
                 (?!) means 'not followed by ""', which always fails)
(?=\))          Succeeded by a )
```

Answer (score 0):

As another option you could iterate through a string, and use a counter for parentheses: increase by 1 for "`(`" and decrease for "`)`". Stop when the counter is zero, or the end of string is reached:

```
var str = "StrA(StrB(StrC,StrD)(StrE)) StrF";
string result = null;
int count = 0;
var firstIndex = str.IndexOf('(');
if (firstIndex != -1)
{
    count++;
    for (int i = firstIndex + 1; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (str[i])
        {
            case '(':
                count++;
                break;
            case ')':
                count--;
                break;
        }

        if (count == 0)
        {
            result = str.Substring(firstIndex + 1, i - firstIndex - 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```